# Running groovy from command line

Tags: groovy

When we run the groovy script from grrovyConsole,'Result' contains the value that we return in the script.

Can i get the Result value when running the script from command line?
if yes How?

Answer (score 1):

Simply `println` the resulting value at the end of your script and it will be written to the console.